# Customise authorization pop-up

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to add text or modify the information displayed on the authorization box that appears when a user has to enable a script?

In its current form the box is far too terse for my users to stand any chance granting access to the script. This will be deployed on an internal domain space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize the authorization dialogs at this time.

When I roll out scripts for organizations, I usually send a brief introductory email that includes a list of instructions on how to access the tool, and I include a mention of the authorization process in that list. I've had good success with users by taking that approach.

EG:

1. Click this link to load the tool: [link]
2. Google will prompt you to authorize the script, click allow so it may access XYZ for the purpose of ZYX
3. ...